# How to execute kudu query with impala or hive jdbc driver(using jdbcTemplate.update method)

Tags: java, spring, hive, impala, kudu

When I try to execute the kudu query, with the help of hive jdbc driver, I'm getting an exception.

Java code:

```
    String createStmt =  "CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cnxamd_core.a_9999_cnxa_hdfs_stats_V_2_forview(\n" +
            "bytes bigint COMMENT 'File Size in Bytes' ,\n" +
            "dat String COMMENT 'Date' ,\n" +
            "tm String COMMENT 'Time' ,\n" +
            "load_key String COMMENT 'LOAD_KEY AS DEFINED DURING WORKFLOW PROCESS' ,\n" +
            "fn String COMMENT 'File Name' ,CDL_DATETIME String COMMENT 'CDL_DATETIME' ,\n" +
            "CDL_SOURCE_FILE String COMMENT 'CDL_SOURCE_FILE' , \n" +
            "PRIMARY KEY (bytes)) \n" +
            "PARTITION BY HASH \n" +
            "PARTITIONS 2  \n" +
            "STORED AS KUDU";

    System.out.println("createStmt.. " + createStmt);

    hiveJdbcTemplate.update(createStmt);
```

Error:

> java.sql.SQLException: [Cloudera]HiveJDBCDriver ERROR
>   processing query/statement. Error Code: 40000, SQL state:
>   TStatus(statusCode:ERROR_STATUS,
>   infoMessages:[*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:Error
>   while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 8:19 cannot
>   recognize input near ')' 'PARTITION' 'BY' in enable
>   specification:17:16,
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation:toSQLException:Operation.java:329,
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:prepare:SQLOperation.java:207,
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:runInternal:SQLOperation.java:290,
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation:run:Operation.java:260,
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:executeStatementInternal:HiveSessionImpl.java:504,
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:executeStatementAsync:HiveSessionImpl.java:490,
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService:executeStatementAsync:CLIService.java:295,
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService:ExecuteStatement:ThriftCLIService.java:507,
>   org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement:getResult:TCLIService.java:1437,
>   org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement:getResult:TCLIService.java:1422,
>   org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction:process:ProcessFunction.java:39,
>   org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor:process:TBaseProcessor.java:39,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge$Server$TUGIAssumingProcessor:process:HadoopThriftAuthBridge.java:567,
>   org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess:run:TThreadPoolServer.java:286,
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor:runWorker:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142,
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker:run:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617,
>   java.lang.Thread:run:Thread.java:745,
>   *org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseException:line 8:19 cannot recognize input near ')' 'PARTITION' 'BY' in enable
>   specification:22:6,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver:parse:ParseDriver.java:221,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseUtils:parse:ParseUtils.java:75,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseUtils:parse:ParseUtils.java:68,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver:compile:Driver.java:564,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver:compileInternal:Driver.java:1425,
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver:compileAndRespond:Driver.java:1398,
>   org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:prepare:SQLOperation.java:205],
>   sqlState:42000,